# div[id]=function cannot able to call the respective typescript function?

Tags: angular

I need to pass a list of Employee values from html to the typescript function .I need to to change the image of the employee transaction record based on the Five conditions in typescript,For which i am using Div [id]=function.The function based on the condition returns respective css class name.Since i have 5 conditions i could not able to use ngif and additionaly i need to pass the List of employees .The html code above this also has a list of  employee list,Which i am already looping it above.The issue is this function declared in html is not calling the respective ts function .So please tell me whether the approach is correct or need to change .

```
**HTML**
       <div [id]="getEmployeeId(Employee)">
        <div id="h31">
        <em class="" style="font-size: 0.7rem;font-weight: bold;"></em>
        </div>
       </div>
**TS**
getEmployeeId(Employee) {
  
    for (var EmployeeList of Employee){
        if ((EmployeeList.EmployeeStatus== 'Active')  {
          this.inputDisabled = false;
          return 'circle3'; //noicon 
        }
        else if ((EmployeeList.IsEmpty== true) {
          this.inputDisabled = true;
          return 'circle4'; //orange
        }
        else if (EmployeeList.Employeestatus == 'Error') {
          this.inputDisabled = true;
          return 'circle6'; //red
        }
        else if (EmployeeList.transactionStatus == 'Completed') {
          this.inputDisabled = true;
          return'circle2'; //green
        }
        else if (EmployeeList.transactionStatus == 'Screened')  {
          this.inputDisabled = true;
          return 'circle5'; //blue
        }
      }
  
  }


**CSS**

 #circle2{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px 25px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: #a9d18e;
  display: flex;
```

Comment: I see getId function, but where is your getEmployeeId function pls ?

Comment: You really shouldn't call functions in template. They are called on each change detection and will slow down your application.

Comment: @moqiyuanshi edited the question,I am calling getEmployeeId function only

Comment: @AJT82 any idea on how to approach for my requirement

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug, the function works,  I get undefined for the ID even it returns nothing. try to put un debugger or console.log in the function. 
By the way @AJT82 is right, U should avoid use this methode, that damage the performance. the right way is declare a employee class with ID property, it'll be simple and more readable

Comment: Thanks @moqiyuanshi Can you please share refrence link which explains the same